# Can’t find component Unity

Tags: unity, c#, physics, game-component, cloth

so, I want to add a Cloth component.
I click on a gameobjects, press “Add Component” in the Inspector search “Cloth”
And nothing comes up.

From my searches in google, nobody had such a problem ever, nor is there any answers.

How can I fix it?
Or reload/reimport the physics components?

- Unity version 2019

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Cloth.html

Cloth is in `Physics` sub-menu according to docs.

Comment: @disc_code22 I know, it should be there but it isn’t.

Comment: Cloth was added in Unity 2017.3, are you on that version or newer?

Comment: My version is 2019

Comment: What's your version more exactly (e.g. 2019.3.0b6)? What's your render pipeline (standard 2D or 3D, LWRP/Universal, HDRP)? Have you tried restarting Unity? Or seeing if you can add Cloth to another game object, or in another scene? Doing these things might root out the problem, and it's hard to guess with next to no info.

Comment: Yes sorry for delay, it’s just that project, if I create a new project from scratch Cloth is there. My version is 2019.1f. Standard rendering pipeline